# How to find a specific object on hierarchy

Tags: plone

I'm trying to get a specific object on hierarchy to set a custom index.
I usually get the object using request.PARENTS

```
def getHierarchyObject(obj):
    cparents = obj.request.get('PARENTS')
    for cparent in cparents:
        if cparent.Type() == u'SpecificType':
            return cparent
    return false
```

But it doesn't work to set the index, the parents request is empty.
I created the index following this link:
http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/advanced/catalog

I'll need to climb all levels using `aq_parent()` to find the object?

Comment: What do you mean by `metadata`?

Comment: Sorry, tt should be `to define the index`

Comment: Right, so during indexing you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PARENTS` in the request is the sequence of objects that where traversed over to get to the published object.

You cannot rely on that value if you need to index your objects, as they are not going to be published.

Instead use their acquisition chain:

```
from Acquisition import aq_inner, aq_chain

def getParentObject(obj, type):
    for parent in aq_chain(aq_inner(obj)):
        if parent.Type() == type:
            return parent
```